# How to access session in twig?

Tags: 8, theming, sessions

I wondering how to access to session in twig ?

In my Controller I have this part of code :

```
   $tempstore = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('mdm_user');
   $tempstore->set('num_donateur', $num_donateur);
```

I tried to display the session in my twig template :

```
  {% set mdm_session = app.session.get('mdm_user') %}
  {{ dump(mdm_session) }}
```

But nothing is displayed. Even session is inaccessible.

```
  {{ dump(session) }}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399389/accessing-session-from-twig-template) should clear it up

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your answer. I tested 2 solutions, but in the drupal controller I don't access to $this ($this->get('session')), and add global in twigEnvironment doesn't work. ($twig->addGlobal('session', $_SESSION);)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to firstly check if the data is stored in num_donateur variable successfully using **$tempstore->get('num_donateur')**

If not stored then try to save it using **\Drupal::service('tempstore.private')**, As i have just googled it and seen **user.private_tempstore is deprecated**  [ https://www.drupal.org/project/entity/issues/2951683 ]

If data is stored successfully then use code to print the variable

**{% set mdm_session = app.session.get('mdm_user') %}
{{ mdm_session }}**

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
{% set varname = app.session.get('varname') %}
```

This is the session value `{{varname}}`